# Get all rows with specific time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have a table like this:

```
|user_name|pw|register_date|last_time_entered
```

I want to get all the rows where last_seen_date - register_date < 7

I dont know how to write this query i thought about something like this

```
SELECT * FROM workoutlog_1.personal 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, workoutlog_1.personal.register_date, workoutlog_1.personal.last_time_entered) < 7;
```

But i get this error:

```
Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What's your dbms, mysql, sql server, other ?

Comment: datediff has two arguments. I think argument "day" is wrong.

Comment: If your using mySQL then date diff only takes two parameters [see here for details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error code seems to come from mysql.

With mysql, [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) takes only 2 parameters (`day` is not needed)

I think that in (really) old versions, it took 3 parameters, now it works only with 2, and it will return days.

If you had to work with another unit (hour for example), you could use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Answer (score 0):

MySql's [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) differs from [SqlServers DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) in that it takes only 2 date parameters, and returns the difference in days. Since you want days anyway, just remove the `day` parameter, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM workoutlog_1.personal 
WHERE DATEDIFF(workoutlog_1.personal.register_date, 
               workoutlog_1.personal.last_time_entered) < 7;
```